# Stripe payment checkout mehod can we set own parameter which we will received in a webhook

Tags: curl, stripe-payments, checkout

I am using strip payment gateway for checkout/session api

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions \
-u sk_test_123: \
-d success_url="https://google.com/success" \
-d cancel_url="https://yahoo.com/cancel" \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][currency]"=USD \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]"=ABC \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]"=150 \
-d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
-d mode=payment
```

can i set any parameter or identifiers manually in this which I will received in success strip web-hooks ?

Comment: have you seen [`{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url) in the docs?

Comment: You shared your test API key and should roll it: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions \
-u sk_test_123: \
-d success_url="https://google.com/success" \
-d cancel_url="https://yahoo.com/cancel" \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][currency]"=USD \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]"=ABC \
-d "line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]"=150 \
-d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
-d "metadata[order_id]"=waybill \
-d mode=payment
```

You can set metadata and you will received it in checkout.session.completed

Comment: Note you shared your test API key and should roll it: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys